# How to compare counts in django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have model like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
  done = models.Boolean()
```

And want to check if all `done` are `True`:

```
A.objects.count() == A.objects.filter(done=True).count()
```

But how to do the same thing inside DB in one query?

```
???
A.objects.annotate(Count('done??')).aggregate(??)
???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should filter on done=False and check if there are any results with `exists`.

```
 A.objects.filter(done=False).exists()
```

Comment: This is definitely a correct answer, but I still wonder how to do the aggregation in question though (might be useful for future me). Any hints?